# Work of getMenuInflater?

Tags: java, android

So I am working on a project i.e Basic weather application. I am a beginner in android.

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
```

I don’t know what is the use of getMenuInfalter method here. We can use inflate method using inflater object as it is a method of MenuInflater class.

Comment: So a guy wals into a bar... and the bartender tells him: Read a tutorial / manual please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is no need if you don't want to reuse the instance again

so you can do `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);`

Although `getMenuInfalter` reruns an instance of `MenuInflater` which is used to create menus from preprocessed XML

> I don’t know what is the use of getMenuInfalter method here. We can
>   use inflate method using inflater object as it is a method of
>   MenuInflater class

Because `getMenuInfalter` is a call to a concrete method in parent class which internally confirms the linking of appropriate theme with the current activity and if there is no action bar then yes you can directly initialize the instance yourself, as shown in the source code

```
public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
        // Make sure that action views can get an appropriate theme.
        if (mMenuInflater == null) {
            initWindowDecorActionBar();
            if (mActionBar != null) {
                mMenuInflater = new MenuInflater(mActionBar.getThemedContext(), this);
            } else {
                // initialize instance with context
                mMenuInflater = new MenuInflater(this);
            }
        }
        return mMenuInflater;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inflating means to read the XML file that describes a layout (or GUI element) and to create the actual objects that correspond to it, and thus make the object visible within an Android app. Answer was taken [here](https://coderanch.com/t/591484/inflater). getMenuInflater is initialization type where the names sound self obvious I think.